# Tungsten Carbide grades

Tags: power-tools, tool-selection, cutting, carbide

A lot of different tools from saw blades to router bits use different carbide "C" grades. I read and there are types like C2, C3, K10. What is the difference between all these? A description on each would be great if there is a difference.

Comment: The difference is in wear resistance vs. shock resistance (these are inversely proportional), and of course price. Practically, you can pretty much ignore it unless you intend to cut through steel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding C1, C2, ... C6 carbide grades, higher numbers mean harder, but at the same time more brittle. C1 carbide cuts softer metals like aluminum and C6 carbide cuts hardest metals like steel.

What is important for woodworking is that the carbide grade doesn't make much difference when cutting wood, if any. I tend to prefer lower carbide grades, because if I drop a router bit or a saw blade accidentally, it is more likely to survive the impact, because the cutters are less brittle.